# jQuery: How to find an object with a certain property equals a certain value?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I iterate through an array of objects and return the one that meets certain criteria?

Comment: This depends entirely on what the objects are and what the condition is.  We need some sample data.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post some code>

Comment: Each object has ID and Amount properties.  An array contains a dozen or so objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function:

```
var matches = jQuery.grep(array, function(item) {
    // this is a reference to the element in the array
    // you can do any test on it you want
    // return true if you want it to be in the resulting matches array
    // return false if you don't want it to be in the resulting matches array

    // for example: to find objects with the Amount property set to a certain value
    return(item.Amount === 100);
});
// matches contains all objects that matches
if (matches.length) {
    // first match is in matches[0]
}
```

If your condition you want to test for is anything other than a strict equality, then you will have to use some sort of array iteration that executes your custom comparison.  You could do it with `.each()` or with `.grep()` depending upon what type of output you want.

If you condition was a strict equality, you could use `jQuery.inArray()`.

Obviously, you don't need jQuery for this as you could just iterate through the array yourself in plain javascript and implement whatever test you wanted.  One advantage of using plain javascript is that you can break out of the iteration when you've found the result you want.

In regular javascript:

```
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (array[i].Price === 100) {
        // match is in array[i]
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this can be similarly implemented as `Generic Lists / lambda .Where(n=>...)` in C#

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation ```this``` is bound to the global window object, not the item. The item is the first parameter of that function.

Comment: @Andy - Thx - I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$([1,2,2,4]).filter(function(i,n){return n==2;});
```

this will return both 2's

basically the array can be an array of dom elements or any array actually, if it is a array returned by a jQuery selector you can do some thing like

```
$('div.someClass').filter(function(){return $(this).hasClass('someOtherClass')})
```

just for eg-> this will return all divs which have both someClass and someOtherClass (note: there are other ways to do this)

updating as per your comment, you can do

```
$(yourArray).filter(function(i,n){return n.Amount && n.Amount == conditionValue;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery to do what you need:

```
var objects = [{id:23, amount:232}, {id:42, amount: 3434}, ...]

// the function which finds the object you want, pass in a condition function
function findObject(objectMeetsCondition){
     for(var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++){
        if(objectMeetsCondition(objects[i])) return objects[i];
     }
}

// your custom condition that determines whether your object matches
function condition(obj){
   return obj.amount == 3434;
}

findObject(condition); // returns {id:42,amount:3434}
```